# Open source projects using cppUnit?

Tags: c++, c, cppunit

I want to know if there is some open source projects (I prefer C projects) that use the cppUnit for the unit tests.

Comment: Why was this closed?  Presumably the OP wants to see some real-world examples of using cppUnit to test C code, which seems like a valid question.

Comment: @RichieHindle: From the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask): You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: How is this question not practical or answerable?  An answer would be a pointer to an open source project using cppUnit to test C code.  It's the exact opposite of chatty and open-ended - either a project meets the criteria or it doesn't.  No chat possible.

Comment: You might consider this framework instead: http://cunit.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @CrazyEddie I tried the check unit test frame work and it works well. but I want to play with cppUnit because I want to use acommon frame work for all my projects what ever it's a c project or a c++ project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Xnor midi](https://github.com/x37v/xnormidi), [tada](https://github.com/quantumelixir/tada) and [nkbase](https://github.com/akashkgarg/nkbase) use CppUnit. I believe [gnuradio](http://gnuradio.org/) also uses CppUnit.
A quick search on github goes a long way.